# Opening a new javascript window via applescript WITHOUT a previous window existing

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript

Trying to open a URL in a pop-up style window. The below script works fine, but when the user does not already have any windows open, it does not work. I guess my question is, can I execute Javascript without an active window?

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
set theURL to "http://www.google.com"
do JavaScript ("window.open('" & theURL & "','_blank','titlebar=0');") in document 1
end tell
```

I could just have it open a new window before the Javascript, but it would be ideal for just the pop-up window to exist without having to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me (running Mac OS X 10.6.8 & Safari 5.1.2), key to the solution was the `reopen` command. Whether Safari is running or not, this will result in a new Safari window showing the homepage. And you need a page (a "document") to run your JavaScript.

Since we open that window just for the purpose of issuing the JavaScript command that opens a pop-up, we can get rid of it by remembering it in a variable and closing it later. This is, of course, optional and only makes sense if there was no open Safari window at script execution. Which you can easily test for by doing `count every window`.

```
tell application "Safari"
    reopen -- unlike activate, this opens a window
    set theURL to "http://www.google.com"
    set currentTab to tab 1 of window 1
    do JavaScript ("window.open('" & theURL & "','_blank','titlebar=0');") in document 1
    close currentTab
end tell
```

Comment: I've found that "reopen" won't work as expected if you have other windows open. Use `make new document` instead.